# Pass md5 hash as argument to my smarty function

Tags: smarty

I need to pass md5 hash of some text in my smarty function like that:

```
{my_func id={$myString|md5} ...}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was simple:

```
{my_func id=$myString|md5 ...}
```